# How can I Change value inside array of schemes inside schema with mongoose or mongodb query.?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

i have the following schema type:
Paitnet:

```
var PaitentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    name: String,
    protocol: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Protocol'
    },

    treatmentTypes: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'TreatmentType'
    }],

    accesses: [AccessSchema],
    reports: [ReportSchema],
}, { collection: ' Paitents' });
```

and the AccessSchema:

```
var AccessSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    stageBool: Boolean,
    exerciseBool: [{ type: Boolean }]

});
```

and what I'm trying to do is to **update** the exerciseBool array for example change one of the values in the array from 'false' to 'true'.
I have tried this code  and its work for me but the Problem is that I get the index from the client so I need to embed the indexes in **dynamically way** (not always 0 and 1)

here is what I did(not dynamically ):

```
  const paitent = await Paitent.updateOne({ username: req.params.username }, 
        { $set: { "accesses.0.exerciseBool.1": true } });
```

I want to do something like this but in dynamically indexes way.
please someone can help me?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, indexes are known but values may change.

you can use the following to create your query.

```js
const accessesIndex = 0;
const exerciseBoolIndex = 1;

const update = { $set: { [`accesses.${accessesIndex}.exerciseBool.${exerciseBoolIndex}`]: true } };

console.log(update);

//const paitent = await Paitent.updateOne({ username: req.params.username }, update); // run your update query like this
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

---

### Update

Check the index exists or not then only update the record.

add into your query `"accesses.0.exerciseBool.1": { $exists: true }` to make sure the `accesses.0.exerciseBool.1` exists in the record.

```js
const accessesIndex = 0;
const exerciseBoolIndex = 1;

const username = 'abc';

const key = `accesses.${accessesIndex}.exerciseBool.${exerciseBoolIndex}`;

const query =  { username, [key]: { "$exists": true } };

console.log('query:', query);

const update = { $set: { [key]: true } };

console.log('update:', update);
```

Update Working demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/GNOuZr3wqqw

No update demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/nsTC8s-ruyo

Comment: @ Tushar There is one problem with your approach if the array doesn't contain elements in the input `index` then it will create `index - n` number of elements. For example if array has 3 elements and you pass index as 10 then it will create 7 more elements with null value inside the array.

Comment: @DheemanthBhat Thank you for your feedback updated the answer :)

Comment: @DheemanthBhat Kudos to your edge case thinking, cheers mate :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongoDB version >= 4.4. you can use [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) along with *[update-with-aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)* to update array dynamically. Try this:

```js
let index1 = 0;
let index2 = 1;

db.patients.updateOne(
    { username: "dhee" },
    [
        {
            $set: {
                accesses: {
                    $function: {
                        body: function(accesses, index1, index2) {
                            if (accesses[index1] != null
                                && accesses[index1].exerciseBool[index2] != null) {
                                accesses[index1].exerciseBool[index2] = true;
                            }

                            return accesses;
                        },
                        args: ["$accesses", index1, index2],
                        lang: "js"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
);
```